# Android Twilio Unable to create/send REGISTER: Object is busy (PJSIP_EBUSY)?

Tags: android, twilio

I have Integrated the Twilio latest android sdk in my android app, I can able to make the call at fist time, When I Make the call again and again app is unfortunately closed. it is showing the following Error. 
Could you please any one help.

The Error is.

```
Unable to create/send REGISTER: Object is busy (PJSIP_EBUSY) [status=171001]

11-19 14:07:39.039    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe E/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:39.038    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=302 (Moved Temporarily)
11-19 14:07:39.058    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe A/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:39.058    pjsua_acc.c  .....Unable to create/send REGISTER: Object is busy (PJSIP_EBUSY) [status=171001]
11-19 14:07:39.060    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe E/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:39.060    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=302 (Moved Temporarily)
11-19 14:07:39.068    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe A/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:39.068    pjsua_acc.c  .....Unable to create/send REGISTER: Object is busy (PJSIP_EBUSY) [status=171001]
11-19 14:07:39.069    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe E/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:39.069    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=302 (Moved Temporarily)
11-19 14:07:39.076    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe A/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:39.076    pjsua_acc.c  .....Unable to create/send REGISTER: Object is busy (PJSIP_EBUSY) [status=171001]
11-19 14:07:39.217    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe E/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:39.217    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=302 (Moved Temporarily)
11-19 14:07:39.222    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe A/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:39.222    pjsua_acc.c  .....Unable to create/send REGISTER: Object is busy (PJSIP_EBUSY) [status=171001]
11-19 14:07:39.355    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe E/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:39.355    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=302 (Moved Temporarily)
11-19 14:07:39.358    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe A/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:39.358    pjsua_acc.c  .....Unable to create/send REGISTER: Object is busy (PJSIP_EBUSY) [status=171001]
11-19 14:07:40.009    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe E/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:40.009    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=403 (Forbidden)
11-19 14:07:40.100    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe E/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:40.100    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=403 (Forbidden)
11-19 14:07:40.186    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe E/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:40.186    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=403 (Forbidden)
11-19 14:07:40.231    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe E/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:40.230    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=403 (Forbidden)
11-19 14:07:40.324    6630-6660/com.iw.tafe E/PJSIP﹕ 14:07:40.323    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=403 (Forbidden)
```